# How to open an MS Access file from an InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, inputstream, ucanaccess

I have using [`net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver`](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to read data from MS Access:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(" select * from students ");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String log = resultSet.getLong("id") + " - " + resultSet.getString("name") + " - " + resultSet.getString("family");
            System.out.println(log);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        File f = new File("files/access.accdb");
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

but now, i want to read data from MS Access as `InputStream`, may be something like this:

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        File f = new File("files/access.accdb");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(inputStream); /*Changed*/
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Comment: This is simply not possible.

Comment: Why @wero? could you give some technical information?

Comment: `InputStream` can be used for one-time reading of content. How should one implement a JDBC driver on top of it? Consequently UcanaccessDriver needs the mdb file for reading, writing or locking...

Comment: Why do you want to use an InputStream?

Comment: In my web project, one user upload a MS Access file and i save it into oracle database as blob, so another user logins in into system and then want to see the and store the data of uploaded file into another table of oracle database, and may want to edit new records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use UCanAccess to open an Access database directly from an InputStream. However, you could use [java.nio.Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) to copy the InputStream to a temporary file and then get UCanAccess to open that.